# Fix seed via srand() produces different results from rand()

Tags: julia, srand

In my Julia 0.5 script I use srand(1234) to get the same results from rand() each time I re-run the script. However, I get different results. What do I wrong?

Comment: More details are needed. Perhaps a bit of code which resets `srand` and shows different results later. In any case, any function which uses the **global** RNG will change the sequence you get - so look for unnoticed uses of random numbers.

Comment: Please show the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

As @Dan Getz mentioned in the comments, this is likely to because you have some code that calls random functions without you knowing about it.

If you call the same `rand()` function with the same seed set, you get the same results as expected:

```
julia> for i in 1:3
           srand(1)
           println(rand())
       end
0.23603334566204692
0.23603334566204692
0.23603334566204692
```

However, if you have another call in your script to rand that may or may not be called, then your random number generator will be at different stages when you get to the investigated `rand()` call. Here's an example to illustrate this:

```
julia> for i in 1:3
           srand(1)
           if i == 2
               rand()
           end
           println(rand())
       end
0.23603334566204692
0.34651701419196046
0.23603334566204692
```

Notice how in the second iteration of the loop there's an extra `rand()` call that offsets the random number generator and results in a different value.

Comment: Excellent answers. Problem solved. In my "main" script I put

Comment: If you think this helps, then you accept the answer so that people can see that your problem was solved. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I'm a newby on stackoverflow. How do I "accept the answer"?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer given by @niczky12 I would recommend that you define your own generator and use that for better reproducibility, that way you always keep control of "your" generator, and calls to other functions (perhaps not in your control) that uses the global one will not affect the random numbers you obtain.

For example, creating a `MersenneTwister` with seed 1234:

```
rng = MersenneTwister(1234)
```

Then you simply pass this generator to your `rand` calls:

```
julia> rng = MersenneTwister(1234);

julia> rand(rng)
0.5908446386657102

julia> rand(rng, 2, 3)
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.766797  0.460085  0.854147
 0.566237  0.794026  0.200586
```